# Getting JSON Response from API Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, response, urlsession

At an earlier point today, I was able to use this API and get a response in my iPhone app.  The fact that I have been trying to debug this for so long is making be believe that I'm crazy! Attached is a screenshot of my console...

[image]

Here is my code pertaining to my API call. Using Apple's URLSession and following many stack overflow questions / Tutorials I can not get this thing to work.

```
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            print("request failed \(error)")
            return
        }
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String], let result = json["result"] {
                // Parse JSON
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("raw response: \(responseString)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Every time I get this interesting `[BoringSSL]` Error and the searching I've done regarding that has not produced effective in fixing whatever bug I have.

Like I said, earlier today I had this app working using the same API.  I have tried the key that the website gave me and the test key they use on their site.  Now that I think of it, I am going to use the exact URL from my code and the screenshot and take a screenshot from the response I get in my browser.  See below:

[image]

Received above response with the exact URL being used in my app.

Comment: Does this help https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92455 ?

Comment: According to your last screenshot, you don't have a data structure indicated by '[String: String].'

Comment: what is appendToBase var?

Comment: it is working for me can you tell what is the value coming for `data`... https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/wvyR5aWjHNUF80Z6kmr1bTuNojfzhmvtcmfBD8QNo9qbNAHy9FvBISINKF3W5i9J/multi-distance.json/35801/35802,35809/km

Answer (score 3):

tried your API in my project. It worked. You can check the difference below:

```
let urlTest = URL(string: "https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/wvyR5aWjHNUF80Z6kmr1bTuNojfzhmvtcmfBD8QNo9qbNAHy9FvBISINKF3W5i9J/multi-distance.json/99501/99501,%2085001,%2072201/km")

var request = URLRequest(url: urlTest!)

request.httpMethod = "GET"
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

let task : URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
        if statusCode == 200{
            do {
                let json = try JSON(data:data!)
            }
            catch {
                print("Could not convert JSON data into a dictionary.")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

> Printing description of json:
>   ▿ {
>     "distances" : {
>       "85001" : 4093.922,
>       "72201" : 4962.6189999999997
>     }
>   }

Comment: What import statements are required for JSON() ? I get an "Unresolved identifier 'JSON' " Error when compiling

Comment: it's swifty json

Comment: import SwiftyJSON

Comment: It is just for convenience. To get readable data from the response.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have to turn off Transport Layer Security, because that worked for me.

> Go to your info.plist file and add a property named **App Transport Secrity Settings** and set its **Allow Arbitrary loads** option to **NO**

Hope this helps.